# Alphabetical ToC counter

Tags: latex, counter, tableofcontents, page-numbering

How do I change the counter in ToC to letters (A, B, C)?

To illustrate:

from

```
1. Section
2. Section
3. Section
```

to

```
A. Section
B. Section
C. Section
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this, before you call \tableofcontents

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter} {\Alph{chapter}}
```

That says for chapter numbering use Alph(abetic) symbols for representing the chapter counter. You'll need to find the right counter if you want to change more than just chapter headings, (\thesection is for sections for example.)